# QPrintDialog isn't popping up correctly

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a print button in a QML pop up with this code that print my rectangle as a QImage:

**myqml.qml**

```
RoundButton {
    id: roundButton1
    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "white"
        text: "print"
    }
    onPressed: {
        var stat = rectangle.grabToImage(function(result) {
            Serv.print(result.image); //result.image holds the QVariant
        });
        console.log("Success: ", stat);
    }
}
```

**serv.cpp**

```
void Serv::print(QVariant data) {
    QImage img = qvariant_cast < QImage > (data);
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintDialog dialog( & printer, 0);
    if (dialog.exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
        return;
    QPainter painter( & printer);
    painter.drawImage(QPoint(50, 50), img);
    painter.end();
}
```

it print my rectangle but first time i click on the print button the dialog window doesn't bring up it runs but in the back and i can't see it until click again on the button .whats the problem?

> I use Qt 5.9.1

Comment: If I understand your question clearly... the QPrintDialog isn't popping up correctly. Maybe try `dialog.setModal(true)`?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS yes you understood correctly .i try your offer but noting changed.it's so strange that if i click again the second print dialog is popping up correctly